# PowerDesigner backend - "Location" in PMTEXT

Tags: powerdesigner

PowerDesigner verion: 16.5.3.1 (64-bit)
Repository backend: SQL Server

In our shop we structure the models in various folders/sub-folders, and the same model name can exists in multiple sub-folders. From the PowerDesigner client front-end, right click on a model while in the Repository (not Local) and select Properties will bring up various properties about the model. One of them is "Location" under the General tab, this will show the full folder structure of the model, something like "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd" where aaa, bbb etc are the names of the folders/sub-folders.

I can find this text string in PMTEXT (the main text table in the backend), actually multiple records with associated TXID. However I cannot figure out how to join the TXID to anywhere. If the frond-end can present this text string in the dialog box, it must be doable. Anybody knows which table.column should I join this to? I've tried all the obvious candidates but no luck.

Comment: The value presented in the UI, is computed. The value you've seen in PMTEXT, is probably tracking Activities, so that would be PMOLOG.LCTN, I uguess.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you pascal, you guess right and now I can stop pulling my hair :-) I find it amusing that the PD UI will compute the path every time and not store it somewhere. The following query will retrieve all physical models (clss = 1548) from the backend with whatever folder location it can find in the PMOLOG table. Not perfect but will do for now:

```
select ob.objt as obid,
    ob.name as obnm,
    ob.brnc as brid,
    fd.tdat as fld,
    br.name as brnm,
    ob.vrsn
from pmobjt ob inner join (
        select objt, name
        from pmobjt
        where clss = 8
    ) br on ob.brnc = br.objt
    left join (
        select distinct lg.objt, tx.tdat
        from pmolog lg inner join pmtext tx on lg.lctn = tx.txid and lg.otyp = 'F'
    ) fd on ob.objt = fd.objt
where ob.clss = 1548 and ob.lvrs = 1;
```